# Spring Boot and Hibernate creates schema but not tables

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I'm using hibernate to auto generate the database schema and tables.
Schema gets generated but not the tables.

How the tables can be generated ?

application.properties file:

```
#jdbc
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/tutor?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
jdbc.user= root
jdbc.password =

# hibernate.X
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5DBDialect
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
#hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
pool.size=2
```

Account.java file:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Account implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String username;

    @Column
    private String password;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate. You already said before you wanted create, with spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create. You're contradicting yourself by adding hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate. That said, I'd use FlywayDB instead, which is a much better way of creating/migrating a schema.

Comment: I tried it and it did not work, surely i'll try using FlywayDB.
In the mean time, any other suggestion for fixing this? thanks

Comment: Maybe you also need spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true.

Comment: `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate` to `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create` ?

Answer (score 0):

This property worked for me:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

With the following, I generated the schema to a file under project root:

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source=metadata
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=create
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=create.sql
```

And SQL server monitoring shown that there's no queries from the app, so there had to be a configuration error or some switch. For me, root cause was a wrong property name in yaml.